# MKMapview not responding to touches when subveiw is added

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, android-mapview, subview

So I have a subview that is added over the top of the a MKMapview. When i add the subview, the MKMapview does not let me scroll around the change the position of the map. However, it does still have all of UI gestures working.

here is my code for the main viewcontroller :

```
 class mapViewController: UIViewController {


    enum CardState {
        case expanded
        case collpased
    }

    var slideUpCardViews : mapSearchCardViewController!
    var visualEffectview : UIVisualEffectView!

    let cardHeight : CGFloat = 667
    let CardHandleHeight : CGFloat = 35

    var cardVisible = false
    var nextState : CardState {
        return cardVisible ? . collpased : .expanded
    }

    var runningAnimations = [UIViewPropertyAnimator]()
    var animationProgressWhenIntreupted : CGFloat = 0

    func setUpCard() {
        visualEffectview = UIVisualEffectView()
        visualEffectview.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(visualEffectview)

        slideUpCardViews = mapSearchCardViewController(nibName: "mapSearchCardView", bundle: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(slideUpCardViews)
        self.view.addSubview(slideUpCardViews.view)

        slideUpCardViews.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 100
            , width: self.view.bounds.width, height: cardHeight)

        slideUpCardViews.view.clipsToBounds = true

        let tapGestureRecog = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleCardTap(recognizer:)))
        let panGestureRecog = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleCardPan(recognizer:)))

        slideUpCardViews.SearchCardHandleBar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecog)
        slideUpCardViews.SearchCardHandleBar.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecog)
    }

    @objc func handleCardTap(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {


    }

    @objc func handleCardPan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            startInteractiveTransition(state: nextState, duration: 0.9)
        case .changed:
            let translationFunction = recognizer.translation(in: self.slideUpCardViews.SearchCardHandleBar)
            var fractionComplete = translationFunction.y / cardHeight
            fractionComplete = cardVisible ? fractionComplete : -fractionComplete
            updateInteractiveTransition(franctionCompleted: fractionComplete)

        case .ended:
            continueInteractiveTransition()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func animationTransitionIfNeeded (state:CardState, duration: TimeInterval) {
        if runningAnimations.isEmpty {
            let frameAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, dampingRatio: 1) {
                switch state {
                case .expanded:
                    self.slideUpCardViews.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.cardHeight + 100
                case .collpased:
                    self.slideUpCardViews.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.CardHandleHeight
                }
            }
            frameAnimator.addCompletion {_ in
                self.cardVisible = !self.cardVisible
                self.runningAnimations.removeAll()
            }

            frameAnimator.startAnimation()
            runningAnimations.append(frameAnimator)

            let searchOpacityAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: .linear) {
                switch state {
                case . expanded:
                    self.slideUpCardViews.SearchCardHandleBar.layer.opacity = 0.05
                case .collpased:
                    self.slideUpCardViews.SearchCardHandleBar.layer.opacity = 0.65
                }
            }
            searchOpacityAnimator.startAnimation()
            runningAnimations.append(searchOpacityAnimator)

            let blurAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: .linear) {
                switch state {
                case .expanded:
                    self.visualEffectview.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
                case .collpased:
                    self.visualEffectview.effect = nil
                }
            }
            blurAnimator.startAnimation()
            runningAnimations.append(blurAnimator)

        }
    }
    func startInteractiveTransition(state: CardState, duration: TimeInterval) {
        if runningAnimations.isEmpty {
            animationTransitionIfNeeded(state: state, duration: duration)

        }
        for animator in runningAnimations {
            animator.pauseAnimation()
            animationProgressWhenIntreupted = animator.fractionComplete

        }
    }

    func updateInteractiveTransition(franctionCompleted:CGFloat) {
        for animator in runningAnimations {
            animator.fractionComplete = franctionCompleted + animationProgressWhenIntreupted
        }
    }

    func continueInteractiveTransition() {
        for animator in runningAnimations {
            animator.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: nil, durationFactor: 0)

        }
    }







    @IBOutlet weak var slideUpViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


    var eventArray : [eventClass] = []

    @IBOutlet var mainEventMap : MKMapView?

    @IBOutlet var eventSearchBox : UITextField? {
        didSet {
            eventSearchBox?.tag = 1
        }

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {

        mainEventMap?.delegate = self

        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpCard()
        let SwipeDownSubView : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapViewController.animateViewDown))
        SwipeDownSubView.direction = .down
        view.addGestureRecognizer(SwipeDownSubView)
        let tap :UITapGestureRecognizer =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapViewController.dismissKeyboard))
       tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        let annosTap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapViewController.refreshAnnos))
        annosTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 3
        view.addGestureRecognizer(annosTap)
        let tapps : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapViewController.addSubView))
       tapps.numberOfTapsRequired =  4
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapps)
        retreiveEventData()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + 5.0, execute: {
            self.setUpAnnos()
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @objc func addSubView() {
    print("added sub view")

    animateViewUp()
    }

   @objc func dismissSubView() {
    print("dimissed subview")
    animateViewDown()
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {

        view.endEditing(true)

    }
    @objc func refreshAnnos() {
        print(eventArray)
        setUpAnnos()
        print("refresh annos called")
    }
// function for collecting the event data from firebase
    func retreiveEventData() {
        let eventDFRef = Database.database().reference().child("events")
        eventDFRef.observe(.value, with: {
            datasnapShot in
            for child in datasnapShot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                print(child.value!)
                let eventObjectTitle = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "event Title").value
                let eventObjectType = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "event Type").value
                let eventObjectLocaiton = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "event Location").value
                let eventObjectDiscriptiom = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "event Discription").value
                let eventObjectLat = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "event Lat").value
                let eventObjectLong = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "event Long").value
                let eventObjectAnnoTitle = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "event Location Title").value
                let eventObjectAnnoAddress = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "event Address").value
                let eventObject = eventClass(eventTitle: eventObjectTitle as! String, eventType: eventObjectType as! String, eventLocation: eventObjectLocaiton as! String, eventDescription: eventObjectDiscriptiom as! String, eventDateTimes: "now", eventImageName: "car", eventlat: eventObjectLat as! CLLocationDegrees, eventLong: eventObjectLong as! CLLocationDegrees, eventLocationTitle: eventObjectAnnoTitle as! String, eventAddress: eventObjectAnnoAddress as! String)
                self.eventArray.append(eventObject)
                superEventArray.append(eventObject)
        }})
print("Retrieved Data")
    }

    func setUpAnnos()  {
   eventArray.forEach { event in
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.title = event.eventTitleSubmit
                annotation.subtitle = event.eventTypeSubmit
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: event.eventLatSubmit, longitude: event.eventLongSubmit)
    mainEventMap?.addAnnotation(annotation)

            }
        print(eventArray)
        print("annos added")
}


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    func animateViewUp() {
  slideUpViewHeightConstraint.constant = 300
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    @objc func animateViewDown() {
        slideUpViewHeightConstraint.constant = 1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
extension mapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        var annotationView = mainEventMap?.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "annotationView")

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotation view")
        }
        if annotation.subtitle == "Track day" {
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Track day")
        }
        else if annotation.subtitle == "Drift event" {
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Drift event")
        }
        else if annotation.subtitle == "Champiopnship event" {
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Champiopnship event")
        }
        else if annotation.subtitle == "Meet" {
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Meet")
        }
        else if annotation.subtitle == "Drag" {
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Drag")
        }
        else if annotation.subtitle == "Rally" {
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Rally")
        }

        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

        return annotationView
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        print("annotation Selected")

    }


}
```

here is my code for the subview that is added:

```
    class mapSearchCardViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {


    var eventSearchResults : [eventClass] = []

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        for events in superEventArray {
            if events.eventTypeSubmit == MapCardSearchBar.text {
            eventSearchResults.append(events)
            }
        }
    mapCardTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
         eventSearchResults.removeAll()
        mapCardTableView.reloadData()
        }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print(superEventArray)
    print("search bar clicked")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("returned superevent array count")
        return superEventArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if eventSearchResults.count == 0 {
            print("event search count = 0")
        let cellIdentifier = "eventTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! eventFeedTableViewCell

        cell.eventTitleLabel.text = superEventArray[indexPath.row].eventTitleSubmit
        cell.eventTypeLabel.text = superEventArray[indexPath.row].eventTypeSubmit
        cell.eventLocationLabel.text = superEventArray[indexPath.row].eventLocationSubmit
        cell.evenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "car")
        return cell
        }
        else {
            print("loading event search table")
            let cellIdentifier = "eventTableViewCell"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! eventFeedTableViewCell

            cell.eventTitleLabel.text = eventSearchResults[indexPath.row].eventTitleSubmit
            cell.eventTypeLabel.text = eventSearchResults[indexPath.row].eventTypeSubmit
            cell.eventLocationLabel.text = eventSearchResults[indexPath.row].eventLocationSubmit
            cell.evenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "car")
            return cell
        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var SearchCardHandleBar:RoundedSearchView!

    @IBOutlet weak var MapCardSearchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var mapCardTableView: UITableView!
}
```

I am just having trouble with the map view and it not wanting to scroll around after i add the subview.

thanks in advance.

Rory

Comment: Try bringing the map view to front. yoursubview.bringSubviewToFront(mapview)

Comment: Look in the view hierarchy after adding your subview, I only see you adding a another ViewController, it's view and a visual effects view over the whole parent view controller. Both of these would prevent touches to the view controller beneath.

Comment: thanks Rlonilleo and Vinoth. Im very new to all of this so how would i go about prevent this from happening? thanks

Comment: fixed!! it was my visual effects view that was stopping me interacting with the mapview. thanks for your help!!